# "No heat, light or electrical energy may be evolved or absorbed during the formation of a mixture." What about heat from friction?

Tags: mixtures

I was reading about mixtures in my chemistry textbook. One of the characteristics of mixtures that was stated was "No heat, light or electrical energy may be evolved or absorbed during the formation of a mixture." Doesn't the heat evolved from the friction between the particles of a mixture count in this context?

Comment: Eventual friction heat is not released because of forming mixture, but because of mixing. If the same work were done by mixing the components separately, the same heat would be released. Note that some mixtures do release mixing heat, when different intermolecular bonding is involved.

Comment: Please cite the source of the quote.

Answer (score 2):

> No heat, light or electrical energy may be evolved or absorbed during
> the formation of a mixture

By including the word "may," the book may be saved from being criticized too harshly. The formation of many mixtures involves the evolution or absorption of heat [Heat of Mixing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_mixing)

In your mind, you are picturing a mixture that is being agitated by a mechanical body (a mixer), and as a result, the mixture becomes warm. Mechanical heat is the result of an agitating motion. In mechanics there is a concept of "Mechanical Equivalent of Heat". It was a historical experiment of its time. See [Mechanical Equivalent of Heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_equivalent_of_heat#:%7E:text=In%20the%20history%20of%20science,totally%20converted%20to%20heat%20energy.)

Answer (score 0):

Textbooks often go overboard in trying to differentiate between mixtures and compounds, physical and chemical changes and similar subtle happenings by setting up rigorous rules that have to be broken if one thinks more deeply about them. However, if one does think more deeply about it don't completely discard the original intent. ALL interactions with matter involve chemical forces; there are some general groupings such as intermolecular, intramolecular bonds, nuclear bonds; there are always instances that are not rigorous. As you learn chemistry you will grow to appreciate and look for and perhaps study these instances or at least not be too surprised if they are encountered. Mixtures are not only mixtures They involve interactions between the components these interactions involve energy, entropy, bond breaking and formation [usually weak] sometimes maybe not. I was just sitting on my porch during a thunderstorm. These are caused by a rapid rising of humid air, condensation of water vapor releasing huge amounts of energy and somehow forming ions. These were initially all physical changes but a nearby lightning bolt and tremendous thunder was far from simply physical. So we got heat, light, sound and even fear from physical changes[there were also chemical changes N2 + O2 reacted to give NO, Interesting because NO is an endothermic compound a chemical change that required energy. The book over simplified! Chemistry is far too interesting to simply learn rules and not think about them. [don't rely on friction as a solution to thinking about things either, it is also a chemical process to be thought about.]